# Prove the inequality $| \frac{z}{|z|}-1| \leq |arg(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove the inequality $| \frac{z}{|z|}-1| \leq |arg(z)|$

Here is what I got

$z=r(cos \theta +i sin \theta)$.

So $LHS= ((\cos \theta -1)^2 +sin^2 \theta)^{1/2}=(2-2\cos \theta)^{1/2}$

Note that $-1 \leq \cos \theta \leq 1$ so $-2 \leq LHS \leq 2$

And $arg(z)=\theta$ and $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$ so $0\leq |\theta| \leq \pi$

Is this surffice to say the inequality is true? I'm still feeling that I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: use this
$$|\sin{x}|\le |x|$$
so
$$(2-2\cos{x})^{1/2}=2|\sin{\dfrac{x}{2}}|\le| x|$$

Comment: quick question: $|sin x| \leq |x|$ is which property? And $(2-2cos x)^{1/2}$ can be negative number, right?

Comment: $|\sin{x}|\le|x|$ this is well know inequality. $2-2\cos{x}\ge 0$

Comment: yes, but the square root of it can be both positive and negative, right, for example, $4 >0$ but its square root are $2$ and $-2$, but i guess i'ts not important, if it's negative than it's clearly less than $|x|$